# JAX-RS / Servlet Programmatic Login

Tags: java, ajax, glassfish, jax-rs

I'm creating a restful service with jax-rs which will be used via ajax calls. i need to use programmatic security as i need fine grained control. i've created a login method (that calls request.login) but when subsequent methods are called the security context method getUserPrincipal is always null.

because i'm using programmatic login do i need to do something else for getUserPrincipal to work in subsequent calls? do i have to set something in the session or have a custom interceptor on calls to check or should it be managed by the container?

i'm using glassfish 4

Comment: note that i'm using multiple jaxrs classes, do i have to pass the login info between different servlets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are aiming to have user sessions, need to keep track of logins using sessions or your own cookie.

If you are aiming to have a RESTful service, you should authenticate every request because REST is designed to be stateless.